# What parameter is need for add the SQL Client Connectivity SDK feature in SQL Server 2008 R2 (Silent Installation)

Tags: sql-server-2008, wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

I need to add SQL Client Connectivity SDK feature, i install SQL Server 2008 R2 using silent mode, What would be correct parameter for adding this feature.. Conn is not working for me.. please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using SNAC_SDK. CONN is for the Client Tools Connectivity.

Comment: Please add a documentation reference if you can.

Comment: Here something (no official doc tho) https://simondrichards.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/sql-server-2012-automated-install-ini-feature-list/

Comment: Here the official 2008 R2 list from MS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#Feature